# How to plot a cumulative frequency line graph using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cumulative-frequency, geom

Forgive me if this question is self explanatory, but I am still trying to get to grips with some more of R's features.

I am currently trying to use R to replot a cumulative frequency with lines I plotted in excel.

[image: Here is a picture of the graph I am trying to recreate]

I think a lot of my problems are coming from having a lot of cells with no data, as I keep getting the warning:

> Warning messages:
> 1: Removed 81 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
> 2: Removed 81 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
> 3: Removed 81 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).

This is because each column represents a recording frequency witch witch only occurred for 21 days, with a 20 day rest period between each recording period.

[image: My data table]

I have tried using `geom_ steps()` and `geom_points()` but I end up with these:

[image: Graphic produced using geom_step]

[image: graphic produced with geom_point]

When I use the `geom_line()` function the axis are created but nothing is plotted.

[image: Graphic produced using geom_line]

The dates on the x axis also look horrendous, I tried using the code  `+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))` to rotate the labels but it still looks terrible, I am not sure if its just to many dates.

Here is the code I have been trying to get to work for the various geom functions:

```r
ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = d2s1, group = 1), data = cf) +
    geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = d20s1, group = 1), data = cf) +
    geom_point(aes(x = Date, y = d10s1, group = 1), data = cf) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))

ggplot() +
    geom_step(aes(x = Date, y = d2s1, group = 1), data = cf) +
    geom_step(aes(x = Date, y = d20s1, group = 1), data = cf) +
    geom_step(aes(x = Date, y = d10s1, group = 1), data = cf) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))

ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = d2s1, group = 1), data = cf) +
    geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = d20s1, group = 1), data = cf) +
    geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = d10s1, group = 1), data = cf) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

I hope this all makes sense and thank you all in advance for any help you can provide!

I read in the data using `read.csv("cf.csv")`.

I have attached the output of `dput(cf)` below.

```
structure(list(Date = c("08/11/2019", "09/11/2019", "10/11/2019", 
"11/11/2019", "12/11/2019", "13/11/2019", "14/11/2019", "15/11/2019", 
"16/11/2019", "17/11/2019", "18/11/2019", "19/11/2019", "20/11/2019", 
"21/11/2019", "22/11/2019", "23/11/2019", "24/11/2019", "25/11/2019", 
"26/11/2019", "27/11/2019", "28/11/2019", "29/11/2019", "30/11/2019", 
"01/12/2019", "02/12/2019", "03/12/2019", "04/12/2019", "05/12/2019", 
"06/12/2019", "07/12/2019", "08/12/2019", "09/12/2019", "10/12/2019", 
"11/12/2019", "12/12/2019", "13/12/2019", "14/12/2019", "15/12/2019", 
"16/12/2019", "17/12/2019", "18/12/2019", "19/12/2019", "20/12/2019", 
"21/12/2019", "22/12/2019", "23/12/2019", "24/12/2019", "25/12/2019", 
"26/12/2019", "27/12/2019", "28/12/2019", "29/12/2019", "30/12/2019", 
"31/12/2019", "01/01/2020", "02/01/2020", "03/01/2020", "04/01/2020", 
"05/01/2020", "06/01/2020", "07/01/2020", "08/01/2020", "09/01/2020", 
"10/01/2020", "11/01/2020", "12/01/2020", "13/01/2020", "14/01/2020", 
"15/01/2020", "16/01/2020", "17/01/2020", "18/01/2020", "19/01/2020", 
"20/01/2020", "21/01/2020", "22/01/2020", "23/01/2020", "24/01/2020", 
"25/01/2020", "26/01/2020", "27/01/2020", "28/01/2020", "29/01/2020", 
"30/01/2020", "31/01/2020", "01/02/2020", "02/02/2020", "03/02/2020", 
"04/02/2020", "05/02/2020", "06/02/2020", "07/02/2020", "08/02/2020", 
"09/02/2020", "10/02/2020", "11/02/2020", "12/02/2020", "13/02/2020", 
"14/02/2020", "15/02/2020", "16/02/2020", "17/02/2020"), d2s1 = c(6L, 
11L, 13L, 20L, 25L, 35L, 42L, 49L, 49L, 51L, 53L, 54L, 60L, 65L, 
69L, 73L, 76L, 80L, 85L, 86L, 86L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), d10s2 = c(0L, 6L, 8L, 
10L, 11L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 24L, 24L, 
26L, 27L, 31L, 32L, 32L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), d20s1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 3L, 9L, 13L, 19L, 24L, 26L, 32L, 38L, 44L, 46L, 48L, 
50L, 56L, 62L, 64L, 64L, 73L, 83L, 92L, 99L, 105L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), d20s2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 14L, 15L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
43L, 43L, 45L, 47L, 50L, 53L, 56L, 57L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), d10s1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 15L, 19L, 22L, 33L, 34L, 37L, 
37L, 39L, 41L, 48L, 50L, 52L, 56L, 62L, 64L, 65L, 68L, 72L, 77L, 
84L), d2s2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 
14L, 17L, 17L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 26L, 26L, 30L, 33L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-102L)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Help us help you: Provide a [mcve]. In particular, it will be easier to help with access to your data. You can [edit] your question and paste in the output of the R command `dput(cf)` to provide that data in a format that is easy for others to use in their R session.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I have added the output to the post :)

Comment: For `geom-line` you need to add a `group` into `aes`. Also just want to second the point about converting x axis from factor to date.

Answer (score 0):

The function `geom_step()` has an argument `na.rm` to remove `NA` values, which is `FALSE` by default. changing this to `TRUE` should give you the plots that you want. Alternatively you could change the `NA` data to zeroes for the same effect.

The crowded x-axis is typical of what happens when the data is stored as a factor, rather than a date. This will be related to how you read in your data, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Thank you very much for getting back to me! That is really helpful I will give that a try. I read in my data with the `read.csv("cf.csv")` function.